# How to get correct uib-pagination total-items after filtering?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi I have a table which i want to filter based on days check boxes. After filtering i want to have correct pagination total items. Any ideas?

```
 <div class="form-inline" id="overnightsDays">
        <label translate="ratingCalculator.overnight.displayDays"></label>
        <label ng-repeat="day in days">
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{day.name}}" id="{{day.id}}" ng-model="day.checked" ng-init="selectedDays()" ng-change="selectedDays()">
            <label class="overnights-display-rating margin-less" for="{{day.id}}" translate="ratingCalculator.overnight.{{day.name}}"> </label>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="vm.overnights.programs.length" id="overnightsTableData">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="program in vm.tblOvernights.programs | filter: dayFilter">

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <ul uib-pagination total-items="How to get total items per each filtering" ng-model="vm.tblOvernights.currentPage" max-size="10" items-per-page="vm.tblOvernights.maxSize"
            class="pagination-sm" boundary-link-numbers="true" force-ellipses="true" ng-click="vm.setTblOvernightsPage()"></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: data-total-items="(vm.tblOvernights.programs | filter:dayFilter).length"   i'm losing some of the data

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a pipe filter to know to startfrom

```
.filter('startFrom', [
   function() {
        return function(data, start) {
            return data.slice(start);
        };
    }
]);
```

and implement in the tr repeat like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="program in vm.tblOvernights.programs | filter: dayFilter | 
startFrom:(vm.tblOvernights.currentPage -1) * vm.tblOvernights.pageSize | limitTo: 
vm.tblOvernights.pageSize">

</tr>
```